# How do I change Folderlocation with radio buttons in a groupbox?

Tags: c#

I have these Groupboxes

[image]

I want to open a specific folderlocation depending on which radiobuttons are checked in the groupboxes.

So let's say Option 1 and Option B open then Desktop and Option 2 and Option A some Folder on the Desktop.

I know how to run it with a single radiobutton but have some difficulties in how to make it work with 2 Groupboxes.

Comment: You can use `nested ifs` for this case.

Comment: Am I thinking to simple? String path(){ if(option 1 checked in group 1 && option A checked in group two) return "somepath/withsomesubpath/"; if(option 1 checked in ....

Comment: Thanks Aziuth I just made a Button which just checks if option A && option 1 is checked then it sets the path to the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

If you would have shown code would be better to understand your terminologies. For your case you could use nested `for` and `if` like

```
//Some path which ever you want
string[] paths = { Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "C:\\"};
string[] Folders = { "SomeFolder", "AnyFolder", "YesThisFolder" };
string calcFolderPath="";

for(int i=0;i<=1;i++) //this is for group
{
    for(int j=0;j<=2;j++) //this is for option / radio button
    {
        //You have to check if the group option is checked or not
        if(group[i].option[j].checked) //This might not work
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                calcFolderPath = path[j];
            }
            else
            {
                calcFolderPath = calcFolderPath + Folders[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an idea. This program **might not work** as it is because it is not been tested.

This program depicts that the first outer loop would check run for 2 times that is to check the number of groups we have. The inner loop is the number of radio button we have in the groups. Then we are checking if the group's option button is checked or not. If it is checked than we are checking if it is group1 than it is taking the path and if group2 than it is taking the folder name.

Hope this helps

### Edit

After your comment it would be somthing like

```
string path = "";
string foldersName = "";
string completepath = "";
private void optionButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (optionButtonA.Checked == true) 
    { 
        path = "C:\\Users\\z003cypv\\Desktop"; 
    } 
    completepath = CalcCompletePath();
}
private void optionButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (optionButtonA.Checked == true) 
    { 
        path = "C:\\Users\\z003cypv\\Documents"; 
    } 
    completepath = CalcCompletePath();
}   
private void optionButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (optionButtonA.Checked == true) 
    { 
        path = "C:\\Users\\z003cypv\\Pictures"; 
    } 
    completepath = CalcCompletePath();
}
```

Then for folders

```
private void optionButtonA_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (optionButtonA.Checked == true) 
    { 
        foldersName = "SomeName"; 
    } 
    completepath = CalcCompletePath();
}
private void optionButtonB_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (optionButtonA.Checked == true) 
    { 
        foldersName = "NameFolder"; 
    } 
    completepath = CalcCompletePath();
}
private void optionButtonC_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (optionButtonA.Checked == true) 
    { 
        foldersName = "SomeFolderName"; 
    } 
    completepath = CalcCompletePath();
}   

public string CalcCompletePath();
{
    return path + foldersName;
}
```

But this is a very inefficient way of doing the things. I would still prefer the first option.

Comment: `private void optionButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (optionButtonA.Checked == true)
            {
                path = "C:\\Users\\z003cypv\\Desktop";
            }
        }`

So I got this and it would work but the problem here is it works only after changing the radion button in groupbox 1 first and I need it to immediately work.

Comment: You can also run it at a button click after both the buttons has been checked. and can do a validation that both the option button in the groups has been checked before calculating the path

Comment: to calculate the path on the event like `optionButton1_CheckedChanged` might be a bad idea. because than on all the options checked changed event you need to update your string.

Comment: @BlackPanic you can have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah I checked on it :) Can you give an example for the button idea with validation? I think that could do it for me if that is possible.

Comment: I would be very interested in the option with the button if there is any chance for you to provide a sample

Comment: @BlackPanic the first code above could be used for your button event. But you need to create the array of the elements/components. and it would be working.

Comment: Yeah well the point where you wrote this might not work that won't work and the 2nd if(i==0) won't work either that way.